# if statement expression calls function, need to test if true instead

Tags: c++, function, callback, expression, do-while

I am working on an assignment for one of my college classes, and I'm having a "problem" where if I use a function in the expression of an if statement/while loop, it calls the function instead of providing a boolean value.
I need to check if the value of this function is equal to the desired value. I'm sure this is an intended feature, but we've not been taught how to properly check for this, and I've been able to find any reference to said action. Any help is appreciated.

```
string askYesNo(string question)
    {
        string playerChoice;
        do
        {
            cout << question << " (YES/NO)" << endl;
            cin >> playerChoice;
            for (int i = 0; i < playerChoice.size(); i++)
            {
                playerChoice[i] = toupper(playerChoice[i]);
            }
        } while (playerChoice != "YES" && playerChoice != "NO");
        return playerChoice;
    }

void adventure()
{
    if (askYesNo("You see a pile of gold in front of you. Do you want it?") == "YES")
    {
        cout << "As you approach, it moves forward and attacks you!\n";
        do
        {
            askYesNo("\nDo you want to continue to battle?");
        } while (askYesNo("\nDo you want to continue to battle?") == "YES");// WHY DOES THIS CALL THE FUNCTION?
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Okay, cool.";
    }

    return;
}
```

Expecting to test whether function is true. Actual result, it calls function, resulting in function being called twice.

Comment: I suggest to change signature to `bool askYesNo(const string& question)` (or enum for Yes/No instead of `bool`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the function call is inside of an if statement, the function will still be called.  I'm not totally sure what the purpose of the do-while loop in adventure() is, but here is what I recommend:

```
    std::string answer;
    do
    {
        answer = askYesNo("\nDo you want to continue to battle?");
    } while (answer == "YES");
```

This way, the function will only be called once per loop iteration.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Dan. Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. Congratulations, you start off by correctly reading a question which I totally got lost in.... Good work. Have fun going on like that and contributing to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a longtime lurker, and I felt like it was time to start contributing

Comment: I noticed, looking at your profile. Good decision to unhide. Such a nice change to see first answers with explanations.

Comment: The do-while loop is just the "main" event within the program. I basically have it set up to determine the attack of an enemy, compare it to your defense, and calculate health.
I felt those details weren't entirely pertinent since I was pretty sure it was the do-while loop calling the function again.

So you recommend setting the function to a variable, and then checking the value of the variable instead?

Comment: @SeoulP exactly!  You could also leave your while() condition as is, and remove the askYesNo() call inside of the loop.  The result will be the same as long as you only call askYesNo() once.  Thanks for the explanation of your loop's purpose, and I agree that it was not relevant in the scope of your question

Comment: Thank you, Dan! That worked out wonderfully. It makes me wonder how I even glanced over it.

Comment: I was worried that you met one of those "ask, get answer, disappear for months" users. But I see that you got an accept. Happy for you. :-) Well done, SeoulP.